# Spring Security OAuth2 - @EnableOauth2Sso but accept tokens as authentication, too

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application which has `@EnableOAuth2Sso` on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

After adding `@EnableOAuth2Sso`the application redirects me to the authorization server and allows access after login at this authorization server. I want to offer API access as well, so i want applications be able to access my resources by passing an accesstoken via the Authorization-Header

```
Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...
```

I debuged through the authentication filter which is used with `@EnableOAuth2Sso` noticed, that Authorization-Header value is not checked.

After that i tried to create a custom filter and added this filter to the security configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilter(myCustomFilter)
    ...;
}
```

But now i get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0788cea.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0788cea$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7e95689d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0788cea.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

At first i thought i've done something wrong inside my filter but i ended up with a plain filter class doing nothing else than proceed the filterchain and still having the same error.

So i have two questions:

1. Why do i get this exception?
2. Is there a way to allow token authentication for endpoints in an application which uses `@EnableOAuth2Sso` ?

Comment: I guess you mean *@EnableOAuth2Sso* instead of *@EnableSso* ?  Can you elaborate on "redirect works fine" and "Authorization-Header with a bearer token, too" a little bit more

Comment: Yes you're right. I fixed the typos and tried to better explain what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the exception was the ordering of the filters like [@jah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34996107/2576531) said.

What i did to achieve the authentication of requests, containing an access token in the Authorization-Header, is to create a class `ApiTokenAccessFilter` which extends `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. This filter takes a `ResourceServerTokenServices` constructor parameter and sets the stateless flag to false.

```
public class ApiTokenAccessFilter extends OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public ApiTokenAccessFilter(ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices) {

    super();
    setStateless(false);
    setAuthenticationManager(oauthAuthenticationManager(resourceServerTokenServices));
  }

  private AuthenticationManager oauthAuthenticationManager(ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices) {

    OAuth2AuthenticationManager oauthAuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();

    oauthAuthenticationManager.setResourceId("oauth2-resource");
    oauthAuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    oauthAuthenticationManager.setClientDetailsService(null);

    return oauthAuthenticationManager;
  }
}
```

In my security config i used this Filter as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new ApiTokenAccessFilter(tokenServices), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
  }
}
```

I think this could be easier so i opened an issue on the [spring-security-oauth Github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/683). I'm not sure whether this solution is the way to go, but i didn't find another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for your first  question. You getting this exception because you are trying to add a filter to a filer chain without specifying an order. 
The filter chain consist of several filters in a [fixed order](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/c8f598778f3d45e0092385d20593ade6f33e138f/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java#L57). The exception is thrown in the [check for the existence](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ed01213a273732e28a50ad60d8d7e2ea09cca447/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L1016)of the filter to add.
The `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException` in the `AbstractSecurityBuilder` when an exception happens inside it. So a wide range of exceptions happening inside the `AbstractSecurityBuilder` are causing this unrelated exception.

A possible way to add your filter would be to use the 
`addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> beforeFilter)` or the `addFilterAfter(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> afterFilter)` methods of `HttpSecurity`.

Regarding your 2nd question, you should provide more information.

Comment: i will try something based on your answer. if it works i provide the complete solution and mark your answer as correct. i will do it tomorrow

Comment: thanks for the hint concerning the ordering of filters. Brought me closer to the solution. +1 for that